# Intellij annotation for formatter classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a method that wrap String.format for convenience. I found in the settings a way to highlight the format string exactly as how it looks like with "classic" formatter method.
[image]

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to do this from the code itself, with an annotation ? I know that jetbrains has multiple annotation to create a custom behavior in the IDE (like debugger renderer for custom classes)
But I didn't find any that match my need.

The goal is to make this setting ready to go for the new employee.

Edit:
I expect the annotation to do the same as the settings in the screenshot above. I want to say to the IDE that my method "execute" is a String.format like function.

Comment: Hello, can you please clarify your question in more details, what behaviour do you expect from annotation? Thanks

Comment: @OlgaKlisho I edited. I hope it clear now

Comment: There is no ready tool for this, please feel free to file an issue for this in the IntelliJ IDEA issue tracker (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA)

Comment: For people who are interested : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-283556